# Need help with this question: Write Java code which reads numbers from the keyboard

Tags: java

Write Java code which reads numbers from the keyboard until zero
is entered. Only the positive numbers entered are to be added to a
variable-sized collection.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Demo1App extends Object
{
 public static void main(String[] argStrings) throws Exception
 {
  ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println ("NUMBERS:");

  while (int input > 0)
  {
   myArrayList.add(input);
  }

  while (int input < 0)
  {
   System.out.println ("ENTER NUMBERS GREATER THAN 0!");
  }

 }
}
```

This code doesn't work, I'm not sure why but any help with it would be appreciated.

Comment: If that's homework - it sounds like it - you should add the homework tag.

Comment: In general it is a good idea to specify in what way the code does not work. I.e. whether you get a compile error (if so, post the error message), a runtime error (if so also post the error message) or simply unexpected behavior (if so state your expectations as well as the actual behavior).

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly call the scanner to get input like: scanner.getInt() and it will give you the next integer. Then you can try to see if the integer is positive or not

Answer (score 1):

```
while (int input > 0)
```

This is the error. What you're doing here is you're declaring a new variable and compare it to 0. This is wrong for several reasons:

1. There already is a variable named input and you're creating another one with the same name.
2. You can't use operators on a variable in the same line as you're declaring it.
3. You never give a value to the variable
4. You can't declare a variable inside a while-condition.

What I think you're trying to do there is to cast the input to object to type int. You can't do this because a) you can't cast objects to primitives and b) it isn't clear what the integer equivalent of a Scanner object would be.

What you should do instead is create a new variable of type int and use the method nextInt() of the Scanner class to give it a value.

Another problem with your code is that you have two while-loops, one for `i>0` and one for `i<0`. However this does not quite model the desired behavior. Consider the case where the user enters a positive number, then a negative one and then another positive one. Once the user enters a negative number, the loop for positive numbers will never be reached again.

What you need is one while loop that just checks the exit condition (i.e. that runs until the entered number is 0) and inside you should check whether the number is negative or positive using `if`.

Try something like:

```
int i = input.nextInt();
while(i != 0) {
    // do stuff with i
    i = input.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are never even trying to read the input from the keyboard.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Demo1App extends Object
{
 public static void main(String[] argStrings) throws Exception
 {
  ArrayList myArrayList = new ArrayList();
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println ("NUMBERS:");
  int numberFromUser = input.nextInt();

  while (numberFromUser > 0)
  {
   myArrayList.add(numberFromUser);
   System.out.println("Enter Next Number");
   numberFromUser = input.nextInt();
  }   

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your redclaring input each time.  Also, read the Scanner javadoc to see what method you need to read in the number.

Your nearly there - it'll be worth spending a little more time on it

Comment: -1 For suggesting how to solve the problem as its obviously homework and the op nearly had it solved???

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you check that `input.hasNextInt()` is `true` before reading next number or you'll get an exception if there is no number in input:

```
while(input.hasNextInt()) {
    i = input.nextInt(); //now we know that there is a number, so read it
    if (i == 0) break; //stop if i is 0
    // do stuff with i       
}
```

And use `ArrayList<Integer>` instead of just `ArrayList`.